# PHP comparing array elements as a whole

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

For example I have two arrays,

```
$arrayA = [0=>"A", 1=>"B", 2=>"C", 3=>"C", 4=>"E", 5=>"F"];
$arrayB = [0=>"B", 1=>"C"];
```

If I use [array_intersect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php):

```
$same = array_intersect($arrayA, $arrayB);
```

I will get the result of `$same`

```
1 => B
2 => C
3 => C
```

Instead, what I want to achieve is to get only

```
1 => B
2 => C
```

**UPDATE**

After trying answer provided by *amow* and *Ekin*, I realized that there's a limitation to this method. If my arrays are in the below form,

```
$arrayA = [0=>"A", 1=>"B", 2=>"C", 3=>"B", 4=>"C", 5=>"E", 6=>"F"];
$arrayB = [0=>"B", 1=>"C", 2=>"B", 3=>"C"];
$same = array_unique(array_intersect($arrayA, $arrayB));
```

the result of `$same` will still be

```
1 => B,
2 => C
```

where I'm hoping to get

```
1 => B,
2 => C,
3 => B,
4 => C
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array_intersect(array_unique($arrayA),array_unique($arrayB))`
Hope this can help.

[array_unique doc](http://php.net/manual/zh/function.array-unique.php)

Solution with update:

```
$arrayA = [0=>"A", 1=>"B", 2=>"C", 3=>"B", 4=>"C", 5=>"E", 6=>"F"];
$arrayB = ["B","C","B","C"];
$filter = $arrayB;
$same = [];
foreach ($arrayA as $key => $value) {
    $bIndex = array_search($value, $filter);
    if($bIndex !== false){
        $same[$key] = $value;
        unset($filter[$bIndex]);
    }
}
var_dump($same);
```

Comment: i have updated my question, can you please take a look at it?

Comment: thanks... but i must get the indexes from arrayA as the result, not indexes from arrayB

Comment: if i use `array_intersect` alone, having [B,C,B,C] or [B,C] in arrayB returns me the same result; whereas what i want to achieve is both cases should return me `[1=>B,2=>C,3=>B,4=>C]` or `[1=>B,2=>C]` respectively

Comment: I think you can simplify that to just have `if($bIndex !== false){ ... }` for your two cases

Answer (score 2):

Above is true, you can just wrap the intersect within array_unique() as well. Like:

```
$arrayA = [0=>"A", 1=>"B", 2=>"C", 3=>"C", 4=>"E", 5=>"F"];
$arrayB = [0=>"B", 1=>"C"];
$same = array_unique(array_intersect($arrayA, $arrayB));

print_r($same);

# Array ( [1] => B [2] => C )
```

Comment: thanks.. i have tried your method, and i realized that there's certain limitations to it.. can you please take a look at my updated question?

Comment: In that case, the intersection alone works okay though? @TommyLee, I'm still giving a few tries but see https://3v4l.org/JjR34

Comment: if i use `array_intersect` alone, having [B,C,B,C] or [B,C] in arrayB returns me the same result; whereas what i want to achieve is both cases should return me `[1=>B,2=>C,3=>B,4=>C]` or `[1=>B,2=>C]` respectively

Comment: If you switch the parameters and use `$arrayB` as first parameter, with just intersection you would get either `Array ( [0] => B [1] => C [2] => B [3] => C )`  or `Array ( [0] => B [1] => C )`. Are you sure your keys should start from 1 @TommyLee?

Comment: yes i must get the indexes from arrayA instead of arrayB, as i would like to get the elements after the intersections in arrayA. maybe is there other way than `array_intersect` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$arrayA = [0=>"A", 1=>"B", 2=>"C", 3=>"C", 4=>"E", 5=>"F"];
$arrayB = [0=>"B", 1=>"C"];
$result = array();

foreach ($arrayB as $key => $value) {
   if($key = array_search($value, $arrayA)){
   $result[$key] = $arrayA[$key];
   }
}

print_r($result);
```

And you will get:

```
Array ( [1] => B [2] => C )
```

Comment: not exactly what i wanted, what i wanted was result of `1=>B, 2=>C`

Comment: Updated the code to start from 1 instead of 0, that's all you needed i think